# iOS socket based chat, how to receive messages that were sent when app is in the background?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

For fun I've built a little socket based chat application. It is speaking over tcp socket with a nodejs server. Its successfully sending messages back and forth. However, the problem occurs when i press the home button and put my app in the background - at this point the socket seems to be "paused" and all messages that are sent during this time are lost.

I've got push notifications setup for when the app is in the background but since the socket is not active in the app the message never really reaches the app.

How should i handle this? What are my options?
Ive got a few ideas but id love some input here on how people are handling this.

My ideas:

> 1. Add a "loadHistory" method on my nodejs server that sends all the history of a channel. So that my app can call a certain URL and get a
>      JSON formated response with all the messages. Maybe this should be done each time a table item is touched?
> 2. Make use of the new iOS7 background running features? (Im not to sure its possible to keep the socket alive with that)
> 3. Implement a way for the server to know if a message has been delivered, if it could not be delivered it stores the message on the
>      database. As soon as the client goes online again it sends the
>      messages over tcp. This would require a lot of added functionality to
>      the server so id like to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want offline message , the third way is needed, for every message you get, you need to send a notify to the server to tell it the message is delivered , and when you get connected , you should fetch the lost message.

you could use voip, but your app can not receive message if it was killed.
(if you add voip mode but your app is not about voice, apple will block your app)

Comment: Yea maybe this is actually the best solution. Would use a lot less battery as well.

Comment: I think this is right. your app might crash or someone might go on airplane mode... most reliable way is to fetch missed messages on reconnect.

Comment: that said, it makes sense to ask for a few minutes processing time when your app is backgrounded so you can receive messages if the user goes to another app for a minute and returns, but more work for you.

Comment: you can use push notifications to let user know about incoming messages too.

Answer (score 1):

I have also done some work over TCP socket. I gave background support by these steps :

1. Add "Required background modes" key in your plist file.

   [image]
2. Add this code in your AppDelegate.m file

   ```
   - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
   {
   #if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED >= 40000
       if([[UIDevice currentDevice] respondsToSelector:@selector(isMultitaskingSupported)] && [[UIDevice currentDevice] isMultitaskingSupported])
       {
           NSLog(@"Keep timeout alive");

           [application setKeepAliveTimeout:600 handler: ^{
               NSLog(@"applicationDidEnterBackground:: setKeepAliveTimeout:handler^");//task as you want to do
           }];
       }

   #else
       LogInfo(@"applicationDidEnterBackground (Not supported)");
   #endif
   }
   ```
3. When you get your read and write CFStream socket object after a successful TCP connection, add this code

   ```
   CFReadStreamSetProperty(yourCFReadStreamObj, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
   CFWriteStreamSetProperty(yourCFWriteStreamObj, kCFStreamNetworkServiceType, kCFStreamNetworkServiceTypeVoIP);
   ```

After flowwing these steps your socket should receive message in background too and connection will be active till the time you give in "applicationDidEnterBackground".

I hope this will help. Thanks

Comment: How will this affect the battery life of the phone?

Comment: It depends how busy your app, while in background. I think it doesn't use too much battery as LocationManager does while in background.

Comment: you should only use the VoIP setting for a VoIP app! and of course it will hurt battery to keep radio/wifi turned on/active.